# How to use caret in Apex?

Tags: apex, decimal, operators

If I use the caret symbol to represent "power of" in Decimal-based mathematical expressions it throws me an error.

**^ operator can only be applied to Boolean expressions or to Integer or Long expressions**

```
Integer time = 25;         

for(integer k=2; k<=time;k++) {
    Decimal Calculation = 0.02+k;
    LifeSpanModule += 5000 /(1+(Calculation) ^ (k - 1));
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Your question demonstrates no attempt to research this operator so does not meet the requirements of this site. The exclusive or operator is [documented here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm).

Comment: I believe you want to use [Math.pow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_math.htm)

Comment: As I have learned from many learned answerers here, this appears to be an [x-y problem](https://xyproblem.info).  _[In your case: Instead of asking how to use the caret, you should have asked how to incorporate an exponent into your calculation.]_

Comment: @PhilW : I think you should edit the title of the OP's question from "How to use the Caret ^ Symbol in apex?" to something like "How do I use an exponent in Apex?", then add your comment as an answer.

Comment: Downvoted for lack of research, as you could have simply searched "apex operators" and found exactly what you needed.

Answer (score 4):

The ["^" operator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm) is not "power of" (exponent) but rather is the Exclusive OR operator. Instead you need to use the [Math.pow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_math.htm) function.

```
Integer time = 25;         

for(integer k=2; k<=time;k++) {
    Decimal Calculation = 0.02+k;
    LifeSpanModule += Math.pow(5000 /(1+(Calculation), k - 1);
}
```